# real time GPS tracking

Tags: python, gps, real-time, sms-gateway, real-time-data

I am trying to make a RealTime GPS tracking device using python().

## features

i have got 10 fixed locations

```
loc0 = (lat0,lon0)
loc1 = (lat1,lon1)
loc2 = (lat2,lon2)
loc3 = (lat3,lon3)
loc4 = (lat4,lon4)
loc5 = (lat5,lon5)
loc6 = (lat6,lon6)
loc7 = (lat7,lon7)
loc8 = (lat8,lon8)
loc9 = (lat9,lon9)
```

my current position

```
locCurrent = (latCurrent,lonCurrent)
```

## code to calculate distances

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

## doubt

1.)how am i supposed to trigger a function ,such as send an Email or SMS , efficiently when distance is less than say 5 kms
(one possible way is to run an infinite while loop and check it against the distance(here 5kms) , but thats  not very efficient , )

2.)which is the most preferred language other than python to accomplish the same

please suggest some documented **tutorials** regarding the same ,thanks in advance

Comment: is this to run on a phone or something? or a central server? or a pc? or an arduino board? how are you getting your values? could you just do a cron job or something?

Comment: i have just started planning my project .and I am planning to run it on a central server eventually but as of now i  have got a OSX , and regarding the location information i have seen a few examples to connect to a GPS device via serial ports.I need to get the right information and direction to start , could you suggest me some tutorials regarding the same

Comment: if you are getting your data from a serial port you will have to just poll it contiuously so you are basically looking at an infinite loop... if its a phone app that will talk to a central server you will receive queries from the app and there will be no need for an infinite loop... once you get your points you can just plot them on google maps api or something

Comment: also I wouldnt necessarily make it a distance based thing ... rather update every few minutes that way you can show the actuall points

Comment: If you hook a GPS on the server how can the distance from your 10 fixed pos change? Is your server moving?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to constantly collect GPS data via a serial port, have a look at twisted server (it's reactor supports events from serial ports)  http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/  There is an example that constantly gets the gps position over serial - see gpsfix.py on this page http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/  .  It may not be what you want, but it is a good starting point, and will allow you to evaluate that approach with some working code.

Comment: what are the other ways to collect data , for instance what if i fix the gps into my car and want to track its location and if its ,say 5 km away from a fixed location , it will trigger some action , thanks